# Grouping by name of API, but ignoring parameters - Application Insights

Tags: api, azure, azure-application-insights, azure-diagnostics

I am using application insights to monitor API usage in my application. I am trying to generate a report to list down how many times a particular API was called over the last 2 months. Here is my query

```
requests
| where timestamp >= ago(24*60h)
| summarize count() by name
| order by count_ desc
```

The problem is that the 'name' of the API has also got parameters attached along with the URL, and so the same API appears many times in the result set with different parameters (e.g. GET api/getTasks/1, GET api/getTasks/2). I tried to look through the 'requests' schema to check if there is a column that I could use which had the API name without parameters, but couldn't find it. Is there a way to group by 'name' without parameters on insights? Please help with the query. Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This cuts everything after the second slash:

```
requests
| where timestamp > ago(1d)
| extend idx = indexof(name, "/", indexof(name, "api/") + 4)
| extend strippedname = iff(idx >= 0, substring(name, 0, idx), name)
| summarize count() by strippedname
| order by count_
```

Another approach (if API surface is small) is to extract values through nested iif operators.